# jaxws webservice url additional parameter for authorization

Tags: web-services, authentication, authorization, jax-ws

I created WebService using JAXWS. Glassfish generated wsdl, and whole webservice is published under `http://localhost:8081/mycompanyApi/api?wsdl`

How can I add some additional parameter to this url like `http://localhost:8081/mycompanyApi/api?wsdl&hash=asdfa.`

I'd like to do the authorization by 'hash' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to the JAX-WS and HTTP standards. I would recommend you protecting your servlet with basic authentication and authenticate in the client using something like:

```
    dispatch.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, login);
    dispatch.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
```

Code may depends on your client implementation (here Jaxws dispatch)

You can also use Security Tokens or SSL certificates.